# freepascal: JSON and recursive data structure

Tags: json, freepascal

Can fpjson handle load AND save of the following structure from/to json:

```
PTreeStructure = ^TTreeStructure;
TTreeStructure = class
  name: string;
  value: Integer;
  items: array of PTreeStructure;
end;
```

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't look like your real type. Surely it's `record` rather than `class`.

Comment: does that matter? I just simplified the structure to show the key point which is items: array of PTreeStructure;

Comment: A class is a reference type which needs to be instantiated by a constructor. A record is a value type which can be allocated automatically. I would have thought it matters. Anyway, if you must use a class so be it. But in that case I'm surprised that use use `PTreeStructure = ^TTreeStructure` because that's a pointer to a pointer. How is that to be allocated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fcl-json can store nested data (an object can have an array of objects, which can have an array of objects, see the supplied examples)

But that way you store the objects themselves, not the references, which is fine for a tree, but not for cycling structures.

A [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) can be represented by storing a flat array with all data, but store items with indexes or some form of unique ID per record into the array instead of pointers.

If your root isn't the first element, you need to additionally store the index/iD of the root somewhere

Comment: thanks, it seems that I'd better just use fpjson and do the load/save myself.